# update after delete row in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two models I have created i.e "User" and "Communication", and schema is below:

```
user model scheme:
id | name | Email       | SkillType     | user_Need
1  | ijk  | ijk@ijk.com | Mentor        | Ap Chinese
2  | mno  | mno@mno.com | Protege       | Ap Biology

Communication model schema:
id | UserID | CommunicationMode | CommunicationDetail
1  | 1      | Phone             | 1234567890
2  | 1      | Email             | ijk@ijk.com
```

In User model i have `has_many` relation with Communication, and in Communication model i have `belongs_to :user` I am adding communication preferences when user sign ups to the application, and in setting, i am trying to display that user's communication preferences in separate controls.when user submits the settings page, i want to delete each record in Communication that is related to current_user, its working fine and the code is below

```
Communication.delete_all(:UserID => current_user.id)
```

But when I update them from new action in controller, the records are not updating from Communication. and below is my "new" action code:

```
  def create
    @user_basic=User.find(current_user.id)
    @students=Students.all
    @entrepreneurs=Entrepreneurs.all
    @veterans=Veterans.all
    @user_communication=Communication.where(:UserID => current_user.id)
    Communication.delete_all(:UserID => current_user.id)
    @user_communication.update_attributes(:CommunicationMode => "CommunicationDetail")
    render 'new'
  end
```

And I am getting below error at this line '@user_communication.update_attributes(:CommunicationMode => "CommunicationDetail")'

```
Error:
undefined method `update_attributes'
```

Kindly suggest me where I make mistake, waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you are trying to do,

```
@user_communication=Communication.where(:UserID => current_user.id)
Communication.delete_all(:UserID => current_user.id)
@user_communication.update_attributes(:CommunicationMode => "CommunicationDetail")
```

you delete the communications for the given user and then you try to update his attributes with `CommunicationMode = "CommunicationDetail"`.

So, the update fails because there is no record.
I am almost sure that there is a problem with the logic you try to apply.

Comment: so what should I do to update a particular column of a table instead of delete row, after that update it.

Comment: You don't have to delete the row at all, simply update the `@user_communication` instance. In other words, you don't have to execute `Communication.delete_all(:UserID => current_user.id)`, the rest is probably fine just like that.

Comment: if you ommit the `delete_all` part, then you can update the records

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect

[`.destroy_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) removes the elements you've specified. The problem is you're then trying to call the exact same elements with [`.update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes)

You'd need something like this:

```
def create
    @user_basic = User.find(current_user.id)
    @students = Students.all
    @entrepreneurs = Entrepreneurs.all
    @veterans = Veterans.all

    @user_communication = @user_basic.communications #-> based on has_many / belongs_to assoc
    @user_communication.update_all(CommunicationMode: "CommunicationDetail")

    render 'new'
  end
```

If you want to just update records, you don't need to remove them first. You can just use `update_attributes` to insert the new data into the db

Comment: user and communication both are different models then why you are using this '@user_communication = @user_basic.communication'

Comment: Because if you have an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) set up, you can call the data based off the `foreign_key` in your "parent" model (User)

Comment: In your case, I figured `User has_one :communication` & `Communication belongs_to :user`. This means you can call `@user.communication` to retrieve communication data :)

Comment: Schema doesn't describe associations - let me fix my answer

Comment: And btw is there a particular reason why you're using CamelCase for attribute names?